# Hypothesis why getting NaN in python

Tags: python, math, numpy, scipy, nan

I'm currently working on a math algorithm using numpy matrix. Each matrix's element is a discrete number divided by a huge integer(1 million magnitude). I'm using float64 as data type but I'm struggling to understand why I'm getting NaN in the calculus of some elements. In which situations does a NaN can be raised in python?

P.S.: all numerator of each fraction mentioned above are bigger than 0.

I appreciate your help

Thank you!

Below the main points where I load and deal with each matrix's element:

1. Loading values to each matrix's element X[i]:

   ```
   def run(self):
       for index in xrange(self.range_nodes[0], self.range_nodes[1]):
           print "Getting k predecessors of " + str(index)
           list_dict_adjacencies = self.graph.predecessors(self.nodes_list[index])
           print "Got k predecessors of " + str(index)
           value = 0.0
           for node in list_dict_adjacencies:
               node_index = self.nodes_list.index(node)
               value += numpy.float64((1.0/len(list_dict_adjacencies)) * self.X_last[node_index, 0])
           self.X[index] = value
   ```
2. Where all matrices (X_last, X, X_last_top and X_top) are initialised:

   ```
   def gauss_jacobi_method(graph, min_quadratic_error):
       nodes_list = graph.nodes()
       nodes_dict_degree = dict()
       for node in nodes_list:
           nodes_dict_degree[node] = len(graph.predecessors(node))
       top_nodes = map(lambda y: y[0], sorted(nodes_dict_degree.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)[:1000])
       X_vector = numpy.empty((len(graph.nodes()), 1))
       sum_degree = 0
       for node in nodes_list:
           sum_degree += len(graph.predecessors(node))
       for index in xrange(len(nodes_list)):
           X_vector[index, 0] = numpy.float64(len(graph.predecessors(nodes_list[index])))/sum_degree
       X_last = numpy.asmatrix(X_vector)
       X_last_top = numpy.asmatrix(numpy.empty((1000, 1)))
       for index in xrange(len(top_nodes)):
           X_last_top[index] = X_last[nodes_list.index(top_nodes[index]), 0]


       X = gauss_jacobi_iterate_threaded(graph, nodes_list,  X_last)
       X_top = numpy.asmatrix(numpy.empty((1000, 1)))
       for index in xrange(len(top_nodes)):
           X_top[index] = X[nodes_list.index(top_nodes[index]), 0]
       logging.debug(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' ZERO ITERATION')
       logging.debug(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + ' ERROR: %s' % str(numpy.linalg.norm(X - X_last)))
       logging.debug(time.strftime("%H:%M:%S") + 'VECTOR: \n' + '\n'.join([str(X.item(index, 0)) + ' ' + nodes_list[index] for index in xrange(X.shape[0])]))
   ```

Comment: Could you please post a minimal, working example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: *"In which situations does a NaN can be raised in python?"* - in any situation where the result would `N`ot be `a` `N`umber.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, right. So, would you mind exemplifying some situations where it can drive to a NaN? Thank you :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Operations_generating_NaN

Comment: That's sort of like asking: "Can you show some cases where division by zero might occur?" That said, I often see people confused when they try to find the correlation between two variables with zero covariance, such as `np.corrcoef([[0,0],[0,0]])`, and get `nan`s instead.

Comment: Thank you guys, I will keep these cases in mind.

Comment: @jme I thought the same when I saw the question, but if we are looking for the instances when _numpy returns a NaN_, there is more to the story. For example, when I tested `np.float64(5)/0` a warning was raised and `inf` was returned but the behavior is different for `np.int64` (0 is returned). I couldn't find a canonical source of what returns a NaN in numpy so I would vote to leave this question open.

Comment: @Hooked I believe that's because the result of integer division in numpy is an integer, and the integer types don't support `inf` (or `nan`, for that matter). But you're right, sometimes `numpy` will return a `nan` without documenting it (see: `corrcoef`), and there's no one source of such cases. That's why I think that a little bit of code demonstrating the problem would go a long way in answering the OP's question.

Comment: @jme A community-wiki answer that does attempt to document these cases may be useful to others and answer OP's question (though I agree with you that they probably are suffering from the XY-problem here).

Comment: Guys, I've just edited my post to include two points of my code where I initialise my matrices.

Comment: The two primary NaNgenic situations I've come across most are dividing 0 by 0 and subtracting inf from inf.  Then they spread due to secondary effects (summing along vectors or matrix slices where one or more elements are already NaN). During optimization, in my experience, by far the most common primary source is dividing 0 by 0. Check and recheck your assumption that the numerator is non-zero everywhere at all stages. I bet it isn't.